# Change component variable from outside the component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this custom button component in React Native:

```
const CustomButton = ({ onPress, disabled }) => {
  let title = "submit";
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} disabled={disabled}>
      <View style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

export default CustomButton;
```

I am using this inside another component called Dashboard:

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
    ...    


    
    ...

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.searchBox}>
                    <Text style={styles.label}>Username / Handle:</Text>
                    <TextInput style={styles.input}
                        placeholder="Type a username"
                        onChangeText={(val) => this.setState({ text: val })}
                        onSubmitEditing={this.handlePress} />
              
                    <CustomButton
                        onPress={this.handlePress} 
                        disabled={!this.state.text} />
                </View>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.videos}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => <Tile data={item} />}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id.videoId}
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={<Text></Text>} />
                <Button
                    title="Insights"
                    onPress={this.gotoInsights} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I have been asked to pass/change the title of the button (by somehow changing its `title` variable) from *outside* the `CustomButton` component, from inside the Dashboard component, using reference *without* passing a title prop or using children.

Is it possible to do so? If so how?

I think it would involve using `forwardRef`  to wrap the `<CustomButton>` component but I cannot find a way.

EDIT: When using `forwardRef` you can pass props and ref arguments. But what you *cannot* do is give an explicit title prop that is passed the new title (like we would normally do) and then that changes the button title.

Comment: Why do you have this requirement? The easiest and most correct way is to pass it through props. I would push back on anyone trying to complicate that.

Comment: It is always better to keep components pure as much as possible.

Comment: there is no way you can modify a child component directly without using props or state (even `forwardRef` require you to pass a `ref` prop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by others this is not a good architecture at all, but I assume the context is more complex. Basically you need the ref to your CustomButton and the CustomButtons needs a state (title) and a function to change its state (title).

It is probably possible with a function component as well but I do not know the definition to pass the ref, so I made the CustomButton a class Component as well.

```
interface CustomButtonProps extends ViewProps {
  onPress: () => void,
  disabled: boolean,
}

interface State {
  title: string;
}

class CustomButton extends Component<CustomButtonProps, State> {
  readonly state: State = {
    title: 'submit',
  }

  changeTitle = (title) => {
    this.setState({
      title: title,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.onPress} disabled={this.props.disabled}>
        <View style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.state.title}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}

class Dashboard extends Component {
  customButtonRef;

  changeText = () => {
    if (this.customButtonRef) {
      this.customButtonRef.changeTitle('hallo');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <CustomButton ref={r => this.customButtonRef = r} onPress={() => { }} disabled={false} />
        <Button onPress={this.changeText} title="Update" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```